# create contingency table

Tags: r, unix, awk

I have hundreds of  text files with various list elements (in thousands). Three simplified representative files are given below (here row elements as colours).

group1.txt

```
red
blue
red
green
pink
red
```

group2.txt

```
yellow
brown
cyan
yellow
brown
red
violet
orange
```

group3.txt

```
orange
violet
pink
cyan
grey
```

I could create a sorted count table with the following script -

```
awk -F '\t' '{print $1}' * | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

>

```
  4 red
  2 yellow
  2 violet
  2 pink
  2 orange
  2 cyan
  2 brown
  1 grey
  1 green
  1 blue
```

I would like to create a contingency table as follows -

```
Colour  group1  group2  group3
red     3   1   0
green   1   0   0
blue    0   0   0
yellow  0   2   0
orange  0   1   1
grey    0   0   1
violet  0   1   1
pink    1   0   1
brown   0   2   
cyan    0   1   1
```

How can I create this contingency table using awk, python, perl or R?

Comment: You should include that the number three as the file count is an example, and that you have a lot of files to process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an solution in R.

Set up files (this is just so we have an example to work with - not part of the actual machinery for constructing the contingency table):

```
writeLines(c("red","blue","red","green","pink","red"),
           con="group1.txt")
writeLines(c("yellow","brown","cyan","yellow","brown","red",
             "violet","orange"),
           con="group2.txt")
writeLines(c("orange","violet","pink","cyan","grey"),
           con="group3.txt")
```

Most of the work is in reading in and arranging the data: let's say we know that the files are called `groupNN.txt` where `NN` is a number ...

```
flist <- list.files(pattern="group[0-9]+.txt")
grpnames <- gsub("\\.txt$","",flist)
```

Read colour files:

```
col_list <- lapply(flist,scan,what="character")
```

Matching vector of group IDs:

```
grpvec <- rep(grpnames,sapply(col_list,length))
```

Now just use `table`:

```
table(unlist(col_list),grpvec)
##     grp
## col      group1 group2 group3
##   blue        1      0      0
##   brown       0      2      0
##   cyan        0      1      1
##   green       1      0      0
##   grey        0      0      1
##   orange      0      1      1
##   pink        1      0      1
##   red         3      1      0
##   violet      0      1      1
##   yellow      0      2      0
```

(This is ordered alphabetically; I'm not sure how important that is to you ...)

Comment: Thanks @Ben. It is a nice solution when there are limited numbers of row elements (here colors). However if there are hundreds of unique row elements , then the argument writeLines(c("red","blue","red","green","pink","red"), con="group1.txt") will not be practical. Any alternative?

Comment: Those lines are just to *create* the files so that we have a reproducible example to work with.  They're not necessary if you already have some data files!

Answer (score 4):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{c++} 
             {counts[$1,c]++; keys[$1]} 
          END{print "Colour Group1 Group2 Group3"; 
              for(k in keys) {printf "%s ",k; 
                              for(i=1;i<=c;i++) printf "%s ", counts[k,i]+0;
                              print ""}}' file{1,2,3} | 
  column -t

Colour  Group1  Group2  Group3
red     3       1       0
pink    1       0       1
orange  0       1       1
blue    1       0       0
violet  0       1       1
yellow  0       2       0
grey    0       0       1
cyan    0       1       1
brown   0       2       0
green   1       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays, gensub(), and ARGIND:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ cnt[$0][ARGIND]++ }
END {
    printf "%s%s", "Colour", OFS
    for (groupNr=1; groupNr<=ARGIND; groupNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", gensub(/\.[^.]+$/,"",1,ARGV[groupNr]), (groupNr<ARGIND ? OFS : ORS)
    }

    for (colour in cnt) {
        printf "%s%s", colour, OFS
        for (groupNr=1; groupNr<=ARGIND; groupNr++) {
            printf "%d%s", cnt[colour][groupNr], (groupNr<ARGIND ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk group1.txt group2.txt group3.txt | column -t
Colour  group1  group2  group3
orange  0       1       1
cyan    0       1       1
brown   0       2       0
grey    0       0       1
red     3       1       0
yellow  0       2       0
violet  0       1       1
pink    1       0       1
green   1       0       0
blue    1       0       0
```